# How do submodules behave in github pages?

Tags: github, git-submodules

I have this github repository, which is a web page for an open source project I am working on:

https://github.com/o8/o8.github.com

According to github's documentation, this repository is special, as it builds a github-pages site everytime it receives a push. This site becomes available under http://o8.github.com. This works fine :-).

However, my repository contains a submodule under the folder `/oxy`. This is declared inside the file `/.gitmodules` with a public url (`git://github.com/linepogl/oxygen.git`). I expected that all the files inside this submodule would also be included in the github-pages site. This does not happen, or at least I don't know how to make it work.

For example, there is the file `/oxy/hlp/index.html`. I expected that the address http://o8.github.com/oxy/hlp/index.html would point to this file. Instead, I get a 404 error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the related repo I assume you haven't found the answer yet?

Comment: What command did you use to add the oxy submodule, which appears as "oxy @ acace3c" at https://github.com/o8/o8.github.com

Is it possible to include this submodule without using a command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just figured out that the issue you face might be caused due to the wrong URL which you used for your submodule. The bottom paragraph in [the related help page](https://help.github.com/articles/using-submodules-with-pages) says that you should only use the read-only URL of the repository. So in case you used the git@... URL the submodule won't be included. Just use the https://... URL and it will be included and works fine.

Only downside is that this doesn't seem to work recursively :(

Cheers.

Comment: It's been a while, but I am going to check it. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: This worked for me. My mistake in fact was that I used the SSH URL. Just switched to Read-Only and it works fine

Comment: It is not working for me. Help! https://github.com/fiatjaf/inflacao/tree/gh-pages/modules (the submodule you see contains javascript files that can't be find at the rendered site)