# Github pages not recognizing index.html in Submodule

Tags: git, github-pages, git-submodules

### Question

I searched various questions on SO regarding inaccessible submodule matter, but mostly is [decade-old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212800/how-do-submodules-behave-in-github-pages/10067373), fix on it didn't worked.

I am already using `https://username...` link instead of `git@username...` in [`.gitmodules`](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/jupiterbjy.github.io/blob/main/.gitmodules) which is what most of the solutions points out.

Is my Submodule setup wrong, or is it just Github failing to pull submodule?

[image]

---

### Resource

- [Affected Parent repo](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/jupiterbjy.github.io)
- [Cloned Child repo](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/SimpleLive2dViewer)
- Content of [.gitmodules](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/jupiterbjy.github.io/blob/main/.gitmodules)

```
[submodule "./docs/SimpleLive2dViewer"]
    path = ./docs/SimpleLive2dViewer
    url = https://github.com/jupiterbjy/SimpleLive2dViewer
```

- [Folder structure](https://github.com/jupiterbjy/jupiterbjy.github.io/tree/main/docs): `/docs/SimpleLive2dViewer`
- git command used for child clone

```
git submodule add https://github.com/jupiterbjy/SimpleLive2dViewer .\docs\SimpleLive2dViewer
git push --recurse-submodules=check
```

---

Since it worked with local jekyll serve, I am guessing github couldn't clone repository properly - which raise another mystery that deployment didn't reported any errors.

[Other non-submodule sites](https://jupiterbjy.github.io/PaulPio_PIXI_Demo/) on same directory loads fine.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/using-submodules-with-github-pages , https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/hosting-on-github-pages-with-git-submodules-36815856c3f1/

Comment: That is exact 2 link out of 3 I followed for tutorial but I'll try again, lemme see if I missed something

Comment: Oh I see, I confused the article saying to change subdomain *inside* parent repo but actually is done in submodule repo, hindsight is 20/20, thx for reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same situation but didn't have to go as far as the cloning steps in jupiterbjy's answer. I had added my repo X as a submodule of my GitHub Pages repo, but X didn't have Pages enabled in its settings. When I enabled that, GitHub said it would be published at `[username].github.io/X` (ie not apparently requiring the use of a submodule). I removed the submodule from the Pages repo and pushed it, and all was fine after that.

Comment: I checked my configuration, and saw my submodule has Pages already activated - removed my submodule and it still works normally. Seems like I didn't needed submodule after all - could say it was XYZ problem?